# Python module installed 2.7 absent in 3.4, Mac Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, import, module, python-3.4

I searched, but could not find this same issue answered elsewhere.

I installed xlwt using easy_install. 'python' typed into the terminal defaults to opening 2.7. I'd like to change this, but it's not my question, since for now I can run python3.4 to get the newer version I installed.

After using easy_install xlwt, xlwt will import into the python 2.7 interpreter/shell, but not the python 3.4 interpreter/shell.

How do I add it to 3.4?

Thank you.

Comment: Is `easy_install3` or `easy_install-3.4` available? If so you just have to do the same using this command.

Comment: I spoke too soon - I am getting an error, Traceback, lots of paths, and then finally, ImportError: No module named 'Workbook'.

Comment: I was just pointing that: from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) it seems it only works with python 2...

Comment: only compatible with python2, try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt-future

Comment: run `pip3 install https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/x/xlwt-future/xlwt-future-0.8.0.tar.gz#md5=5bead91840dbc4e3068f98079bbfe632`

Comment: Thank you both for your help! The pip3 install worked perfectly - I double-checked this time with a quick import call.